# Web-scraping issue using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the first 200 rows from a webpage. I am starting with just being able to print out the scraped-out data before loading it into a data frame. Still, my code keeps generating errors or sometimes returns an empty list, and also when the code in the container variable is split into two with its attribute name, only the first 77 rows are scraped.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/'
path= xxxxxxxxx

service=Service(executable_path=path)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(60)

containers = driver.find_elements(by='xpath',value='//tr[@class="cmc-table-row" and (@style="display: table-row" or @style="display: table-row;")]')

Ranks = []
Names = []
Images = []
Symbols = []
MarketCaps = []
Prices = []
CirculatingSupplys = [] 
Volume24hs  = []
Hr_percnt_1s = []
Hr_percnt_24s = []
day_percent_7s = []

for i in containers:
    Rank = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td/div').text 
    Name = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td/div/a[2]').text
    Symbol = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td[3]/div').text        
    MarketCap = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td/p/span[2]').text
    Price = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td[5]/div/a/span').text
    CirculatingSupply = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td[6]/div').text 
    Volume24h   = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td[7]/a').text
    Hr_percnt_1 = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td[8]/div').text
    Hr_percnt_24 = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td[9]/div').text
    day_percent_7 = i.find_element(by='xpath',value='./td[10]/div').text

    Ranks.append(Rank)
    Names.append(Name)
    Symbols.append(Symbol)
    MarketCaps.append(MarketCap)
    Prices.append(Price)
    CirculatingSupplys.append(CirculatingSupply)    
    Volume24hs.append(Volume24h)
    Hr_percnt_1s.append(Hr_percnt_1) 
    Hr_percnt_24s.append(Hr_percnt_24)
    day_percent_7s.append(day_percent_7)

print(Ranks)
print(Names)
print(Symbols)
print(MarketCaps)
print(Prices)
print(CirculatingSupplys)   
print(Volume24hs)
print(Hr_percnt_1s)
print(Hr_percnt_24s)
print(day_percent_7s)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse their initial Json data embedded inside the HTML page:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)
data = json.loads(data["props"]["initialState"])

columns = data["cryptocurrency"]["listingLatest"]["data"][0]["keysArr"]
table = data["cryptocurrency"]["listingLatest"]["data"][1:]

df = pd.DataFrame([row[:-2] for row in table], columns=columns)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| circulatingSupply | cmcRank | dateAdded | hasFilters | id | isActive | isAudited | lastUpdated | marketPairCount | maxSupply | name | quote.USD.dominance | quote.USD.fullyDilluttedMarketCap | quote.USD.lastUpdated | quote.USD.marketCap | quote.USD.marketCapByTotalSupply | quote.USD.name | quote.USD.percentChange1h | quote.USD.percentChange24h | quote.USD.percentChange30d | quote.USD.percentChange60d | quote.USD.percentChange7d | quote.USD.percentChange90d | quote.USD.price | quote.USD.turnover | quote.USD.volume24h | quote.USD.ytdPriceChangePercentage | rank | selfReportedCirculatingSupply | slug | symbol | tags.0 | tags.1 | tags.10 | tags.11 | tags.12 | tags.13 | tags.14 | tags.15 | tags.16 | tags.17 | tags.18 | tags.19 | tags.2 | tags.20 | tags.21 | tags.22 | tags.23 | tags.24 | tags.25 | tags.26 | tags.27 | tags.28 | tags.3 | tags.4 | tags.5 | tags.6 | tags.7 | tags.8 | tags.9 | totalSupply | tvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.94445e+07 | 1 | 2010-07-13T00:00:00.000Z | False | 1 | 1 | False | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 10379 | 2.1e+07 | Bitcoin | 48.2613 | 6.13546e+11 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 5.68099e+11 | 5.68099e+11 | USD | 0.0751799 | -0.0335935 | -4.53183 | 8.59029 | 0.209653 | 1.86047 | 29216.5 | 0.0208523 | 1.18462e+10 | 75.7375 | 1 | 0 | bitcoin | BTC | mineable | pow | boostvc-portfolio | cms-holdings-portfolio | dcg-portfolio | dragonfly-capital-portfolio | electric-capital-portfolio | fabric-ventures-portfolio | framework-ventures-portfolio | galaxy-digital-portfolio | huobi-capital-portfolio | alameda-research-portfolio | sha-256 | a16z-portfolio | 1confirmation-portfolio | winklevoss-capital-portfolio | usv-portfolio | placeholder-ventures-portfolio | pantera-capital-portfolio | multicoin-capital-portfolio | paradigm-portfolio | bitcoin-ecosystem | store-of-value | state-channel | coinbase-ventures-portfolio | three-arrows-capital-portfolio | polychain-capital-portfolio | binance-labs-portfolio | blockchain-capital-portfolio | 1.94445e+07 | nan |
| 1.21071e+08 | 2 | 2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z | False | 1027 | 1 | False | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 7200 | nan | Ethereum | 19.0769 | 2.2456e+11 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 2.2456e+11 | 2.2456e+11 | USD | 0.0502369 | -0.388847 | -3.51936 | -0.763876 | 0.343046 | -0.957346 | 1854.78 | 0.0200434 | 4.50094e+09 | 54.4405 | 2 | 0 | ethereum | ETH | pos | smart-contracts | dcg-portfolio | dragonfly-capital-portfolio | electric-capital-portfolio | fabric-ventures-portfolio | framework-ventures-portfolio | hashkey-capital-portfolio | kenetic-capital-portfolio | huobi-capital-portfolio | alameda-research-portfolio | a16z-portfolio | ethereum-ecosystem | 1confirmation-portfolio | winklevoss-capital-portfolio | usv-portfolio | placeholder-ventures-portfolio | pantera-capital-portfolio | multicoin-capital-portfolio | paradigm-portfolio | injective-ecosystem | layer-1 | coinbase-ventures-portfolio | three-arrows-capital-portfolio | polychain-capital-portfolio | binance-labs-portfolio | blockchain-capital-portfolio | boostvc-portfolio | cms-holdings-portfolio | 1.21071e+08 | nan |
| 8.38193e+10 | 3 | 2015-02-25T00:00:00.000Z | False | 825 | 1 | True | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 58242 | nan | Tether USDt | 7.1199 | 8.66969e+10 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 8.38102e+10 | 8.66969e+10 | USD | 0.00270599 | -0.0104449 | -0.0463599 | -0.0570385 | -0.016347 | -0.0718636 | 0.999892 | 0.221416 | 1.85569e+10 | 0.02 | 3 | 0 | tether | USDT | payments | stablecoin | optimism-ecosystem |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | asset-backed-stablecoin |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | avalanche-ecosystem | solana-ecosystem | arbitrum-ecosytem | moonriver-ecosystem | injective-ecosystem | bnb-chain | usd-stablecoin | 8.67063e+10 | nan |
| 1.53855e+08 | 4 | 2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z | False | 1839 | 1 | True | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 1551 | nan | BNB | 3.155 | 3.71383e+10 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 3.71383e+10 | 3.71383e+10 | USD | 0.223376 | -0.250832 | -2.75968 | -20.9338 | 1.17205 | -25.2036 | 241.385 | 0.0295489 | 1.0974e+09 | -1.1272 | 4 | 0 | bnb | BNB | marketplace | centralized-exchange | celsius-bankruptcy-estate |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | payments |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | smart-contracts | alameda-research-portfolio | multicoin-capital-portfolio | bnb-chain | layer-1 | sec-security-token | alleged-sec-securities | 1.53855e+08 | nan |
| 5.26939e+10 | 5 | 2013-08-04T00:00:00.000Z | False | 52 | 1 | True | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 1017 | 1e+11 | XRP | 3.1253 | 6.98154e+10 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 3.67884e+10 | 6.98074e+10 | USD | -0.417038 | -0.951795 | 47.3769 | 37.2266 | -0.659997 | 50.0338 | 0.698154 | 0.0405228 | 1.49077e+09 | 106.089 | 5 | 0 | xrp | XRP | medium-of-exchange | enterprise-solutions |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | arrington-xrp-capital-portfolio |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | galaxy-digital-portfolio | a16z-portfolio | pantera-capital-portfolio |  |  |  |  | 9.99886e+10 | nan |
| 2.64388e+10 | 6 | 2018-10-08T00:00:00.000Z | False | 3408 | 1 | False | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 13499 | nan | USD Coin | 2.246 | 2.64381e+10 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 2.64381e+10 | 2.64381e+10 | USD | 0.00594249 | -0.0057927 | -0.0359594 | -0.0286095 | -0.0212605 | -0.00772583 | 0.999976 | 0.106004 | 2.80254e+09 | -0.0017 | 6 | 0 | usd-coin | USDC | medium-of-exchange | stablecoin |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | asset-backed-stablecoin |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | hedera-hashgraph-ecosystem | fantom-ecosystem | arbitrum-ecosytem | moonriver-ecosystem | bnb-chain | usd-stablecoin | optimism-ecosystem | 2.64388e+10 | nan |
| 1.40403e+11 | 7 | 2013-12-15T00:00:00.000Z | False | 74 | 1 | False | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 760 | nan | Dogecoin | 0.9219 | 1.08519e+10 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 1.08519e+10 | 1.08519e+10 | USD | 0.223288 | -0.967885 | 12.8639 | 7.70454 | 3.55617 | -2.00884 | 0.0772912 | 0.031614 | 3.43072e+08 | 10.0628 | 7 | 0 | dogecoin | DOGE | mineable | pow |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | scrypt |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | medium-of-exchange | memes | payments | doggone-doggerel | bnb-chain |  |  | 1.40403e+11 | nan |
| 3.50073e+10 | 8 | 2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | False | 2010 | 1 | False | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 886 | 4.5e+10 | Cardano | 0.9147 | 1.38403e+10 | 2023-07-31T21:54:00.000Z | 1.07669e+10 | 1.10815e+10 | USD | -0.318404 | -1.13681 | 5.93883 | -16.1587 | 0.691922 | -21.4402 | 0.307561 | 0.0179873 | 1.93668e+08 | 23.1375 | 8 | 0 | cardano | ADA | dpos | pos | alleged-sec-securities |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | platform |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | research | smart-contracts | staking | cardano-ecosystem | cardano | layer-1 | sec-security-token | 3.60303e+10 | nan |

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the first any number of rows from the webpage [All Cryptocurrencies | CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/) ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Sample code for first 10 rows:

  ```
  driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/")
  Ranks = []
  Names = []
  Symbols = []
  MarketCaps = []
  Prices = []
  CirculatingSupplys = [] 
  Ranks = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer']//table//td[contains(@class, 'cmc-table__cell--sort-by__rank')]")))][:10]
  Names = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer']//table//td[contains(@class, 'cmc-table__cell--sort-by__name')]")))][:10]
  Symbols = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer']//table//td[contains(@class, 'cmc-table__cell--sort-by__symbol')]")))][:10]
  MarketCaps = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer']//table//td[contains(@class, 'cmc-table__cell--sort-by__market-cap')]")))][:10]
  Prices = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer']//table//td[contains(@class, 'cmc-table__cell--sort-by__price')]")))][:10]
  for i,j,k,l,m in zip(Ranks,Names,Symbols,MarketCaps,Prices):
    print(f"Rank {i} is {j} with Symbol {k} having MarketCap about {l} and price is {m}")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  Rank 1 is Bitcoin with Symbol BTC having MarketCap about $568,492,505,623 and price is $29,236.64
  Rank 2 is Ethereum with Symbol ETH having MarketCap about $223,175,213,597 and price is $1,857.03
  Rank 3 is Tether USDt with Symbol USDT having MarketCap about $83,828,994,041 and price is $1.00
  Rank 4 is BNB with Symbol BNB having MarketCap about $37,167,422,893 and price is $241.57
  Rank 5 is XRP with Symbol XRP having MarketCap about $36,845,601,938 and price is $0.6992
  Rank 6 is USD Coin with Symbol USDC having MarketCap about $26,492,203,043 and price is $1.00
  Rank 7 is Dogecoin with Symbol DOGE having MarketCap about $10,915,973,423 and price is $0.07775
  Rank 8 is Cardano with Symbol ADA having MarketCap about $10,748,458,652 and price is $0.307
  Rank 9 is Solana with Symbol SOL having MarketCap about $9,605,784,826 and price is $23.75
  Rank 10 is TRON with Symbol TRX having MarketCap about $7,000,126,116 and price is $0.07811
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it. I would love it if you can scrape for the first 100 rows then I could figure out the rest. I think I have a problem with exceeding the 77th row while carrying out web scraping procedures. Thank you!

Comment: @MubaraqOnipede **10** or **77** or **200**, the logic will remain the same. Atmost you have to scroll down periodically.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I just wrote the code and it worked for the first 20 rows. I would appreciate it if I can get one that would scrape for me perhaps the first 100 rows. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried for the first 50 by changing [:10] to [:50] but it printed for only the first 20